# If $p$ and $2p + 1$ are odd primes and $n = 4p$, prove that $φ(n + 2) = φ(n) + 2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

Prove: if $p$ and $2p + 1$ are odd primes and $n = 4p$, show that $φ(n + 2) = φ(n) + 2$.

I'm stuck on this simple question about Euler's theorem.
Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to develop φ(n + 2) and φ(n) + 2 using the proposition: φ(mn) = φ(m)φ(n).

Comment: Recall that $φ(mn) = φ(m)φ(n)$ **if** $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Comment: Note that $\phi(n+2)=\phi(2(2p+1))=....?$, and $\phi(n) = \phi(2^2p)=...?$

Comment: I really cant see a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\varphi(n+2)=\varphi(2*(2p+1))=\varphi(2)*\varphi(2p+1)=1*(2p+1-1)=2p$

$\varphi(n)=\varphi(4*p)=\varphi(4)*\varphi(p)==2*(p-1)=2p-2$

$\varphi(n+2)=2p=(2p-2)+2=\varphi(n)+2$

:(